# Query inside ES aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, latency, elasticsearch-5

instead of running multiple "must-match" queries which are very similar, I'd like to run a single query with multiple aggregations.

I know how to put multiple aggregations in a single query, but is it possible to have a scoped query, kind of like a sub-query inside a single aggregation?

I'd just like to count the number documents for each query (or aggregation in this case)

I'd like for example to combine the following queries into one, just to count the number of documents for each query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
              "foo": "bar"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
              "type": "machine"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
              "foo": "bar"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
              "type": "human"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How would I go about combining the two? simply counting the number of documents for each query?

Answer (score 1):

It would work if instead of match query you would use term query. You would directly aggregate by the field.

```
POST index/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {
          "foo": "bar"
        }},
        {"terms": {
          "type": [
            "machine",
            "human"
          ]
        }}
      ]
    }
  }

  , "aggs": {
    "types": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result would look like this

```
{
  "took": 18,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 6,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 86967,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "types": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "human",
          "doc_count": 46501
        },
        {
          "key": "machine",
          "doc_count": 40466
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

One more option to consider is Multi Search API

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

```
GET index/_msearch
{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"foo":"bar"}},{"match":{"type":"machine"}}]}}}
{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"foo":"bar"}},{"match":{"type":"human"}}]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing key from your puzzle is the [filters aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html). It'll return you the buckets with the counts.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of similar problem, double aggregation with filter.

Two MUST filters, first MUST searches across two fields field_key and field_value, second MUST is set of SHOULD (basically field_type in [address or transaction]).

Size 0 to ignore filter results, and double aggregations by field_type and field_identifier.

Query done based on java library org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:6.4.3

```
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "my-query-value",
                "fields": ["field_key^1.0", "field_value^1.0"],
                "type": "best_fields",
                "operator": "OR",
                "slop": 0,
                "prefix_length": 0,
                "max_expansions": 50,
                "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                "boost": 1.0
            }
        }, {
            "bool": {
                "should": [{
                    "match": {
                        "field_type": {
                            "query": "address",
                            "operator": "OR",
                            "prefix_length": 0,
                            "max_expansions": 50,
                            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                            "lenient": false,
                            "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "match": {
                        "field_type": {
                            "query": "transaction",
                            "operator": "OR",
                            "prefix_length": 0,
                            "max_expansions": 50,
                            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                            "lenient": false,
                            "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                }],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1.0
            }
        }],
        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
        "boost": 1.0
    }
},
"aggregations": {
    "byType": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "field_type",
            "value_type": "string",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
            "order": [{
                "_count": "desc"
            }, {
                "_key": "asc"
            }]
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "byIdentifier": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "field_identifier",
                    "value_type": "string",
                    "size": 200,
                    "min_doc_count": 1,
                    "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                    "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                    "order": [{
                        "_count": "desc"
                    }, {
                        "_key": "asc"
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```